# Why does a PCB with metallic Faceplate on a BLDC motor assembly creates a unit failure?

Tags: pcb, brushless-dc-motor, assembly

I am building a new BLDC stirrer unit which has metallic enclosures and a metallic faceplate for thermal dissipation. The unit fails often and would not run. I opened the unit to see if it was a loose wire or belt torn or any assembly problem, and everything was intact. I checked if hardware components blew on my PCB board, checked membrane circuitry, and verified the code. Everything seems alright. One thing I noticed was the unit ran fine if I used a plastic faceplate since , the board was sensitive to contact with the metallic faceplate. I put a mylar sheet in between the board and the faceplate cut to the precise dimension of the board-faceplate contact region to isolate the contact interference. The unit still failed. The board, BLDC motor, and housing enclosures are all grounded. I cannot change the faceplate to plastic, it has to be metallic for enough heat to be dissipated. I am wondering why a non-conductive mylar usage between 2 conducting surfaces failed but a plastic faceplate made it pass. Any suggestion for resolution is appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like a grounding issue.  Use an ohmmeter (DMM) to measure resistance between various components and the faceplate.  Windings (at least one end) should not be connected to the faceplate.

Comment: Capacitance or eddy currents from the metal plate could be causing a noise issue. Maybe use a thicker (than the Mylar) insulator, even if only as a diagnostic tool.

Comment: Adithi, I was thinking along the lines that @JohnD was when I read his comment about eddy. It might be interesting if possible to try a plate made of ferrite 61 material. If it succeeds then I think it's confirmed that eddy currents are the problem and you can focus in on that for solutions. Also, are you able to consider thermally conductive [ceramics](https://www.cotronics.com/vo/cotr/)?